# How to get kubectl config file from Azure AKS

Tags: azure, go, kubernetes, automation, azure-sdk

I am using Azure SKD for Go but I am stuck how can I get kubeconfig file using it.

For example:

Using my local system I run following commands:

```html
az login -u "id" -p "password" -t "tenant"
```

above can be replicated via azidentity package of azure-sdk-for-go

but I don't know how can I get following using azure-sdk-for-go

```html
az aks get credentials --resource-group "rg" --name "k8s-name" --admin
```

Comment: I got the solution but I dont know how can I perform the unmarshal of response - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managed-clusters/list-cluster-admin-credentials?view=rest-aks-2023-08-01&tabs=Go

here - response object contains method unmarshaljson but I dont know how can I use it

Comment: following is the method - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blame/main/sdk/resourcemanager/containerservice/armcontainerservice/models_serde.go#L657-L677C2